# Updating a Ruby gem from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails. I'm using a particular gem `my_gem` in my project. In my Gemfile I see an entry `gem 'my_gem' "1.2.3"`.

`my_gem` is in source control on Github. I've pushed some changes to Github. Now I'd like to update the version of `my_gem` in my Rails project.

I'm unclear about `gem update my_gem`. How does my Rails project know where to find the latest version of `my_gem`?

**Edit**: I'd prefer not to include a Github path. Perhaps I can publish to Ruby gems instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your gem listed like this example from the Bundler website:

```
gem "nokogiri", :git => "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git"
```

your project will pull the latest source from your GitHub repository whenever you update the gem in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `:git` option in your Gemfile:

`gem '[GEM NAME]', :git => 'git://[GITHUB LINK]'`